# AngularJS dynamic content disappear on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am building some dynamic HTML and push it to the element using below code, which is just working fine.

```
accordionHTML += '</v-accordion>';
var temp = $compile(accordionHTML)(self);
$('#MainMenuElement').html(temp);
```

But if I refresh the page, the dynamic content will just disappear. Is there anyway I can retain the element without using local storage? Also it will be helpful if some explain about this behavior, on why dynamic content is not holding onto like normal HTML to the DOM.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After refresh your page is rerendered and default content (that you defined) is shown. You can define your controller in such way that it will check presence of dynamic content in cookies or local storage. There is no other way to share data between page loads in a front-end app

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So there is no way I can mark dynamic content to attach to the static content without storing in client side! That sounds not good, but I guess I have no option.